# Problem with Listview adding all components

Tags: android

I'm pretty new at androidStudio. I created a xml file with a ListView a textview and an EditText using relativeLayout. When I put the EditText next to my TexTView the ListView "grabs" this component and i can't click on the list items no more. I just want to have one EditText and be able to click on my list.

I've tried changing the layouts but nothing is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
tools:context=".CNE">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaCNE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textCand"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/listaCNE"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtA"
    android:text="Candidatos" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtA"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/listaCNE"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 0dp width in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Yeah I was following the guide in the android developpers site. I changed it back to 10dp but I still have the same problem

Comment: Can you expand on what "grabs" means? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve and what the actual problem is.

Comment: It's like a EditText is created on top of each element of the list so I can't click on the list itself but I can only click on the undesired EditText that is created.

Comment: I just want a list, a text, and a edit text; but I don't know why when i put the EditText on the xml it creates multiple EditTexts into the list

Comment: post a picture of the UI you want actually, so we can help you asap.

Comment: How the design should looked like ? The `EditText` and `TextView` should belong to `ListView`'s item or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what UI you want to achieved but im just assuming a UI here [If this a what your required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wR1n.png) ,then here the .xml .The ListView item is also clickable as you can see on the image it shows a Toast for the position i click

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll"
        android:padding="16dp">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:hint="EditText"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah thats exactly the UI I wanted to achieve. I alreday saw wha tmy problem was. I was doing a xml to define The elements of the ListView. So when I added the EditText I wasnt actually putting a single EditText AFTER the listview, I was putting aN Edit TExt for each element of the ListView. Ty for Explaining the UI I was going for. Ill post my solution later

Comment: Im glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my problem I had 2 Seperates xml files one is "activity_cne.xml" that is the actually the UI I was going for. The other one is "listob.xml" wich define what elements show the ListView Here are the files (I added some componets in the activity_cne.xml file):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
tools:context=".CNE"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaCNE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAgC"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Agregar candidato" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtA"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="agregar"
    android:text="AGREGAR" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/res"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Reset"
    android:text="RESET" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resultados"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="openRes"
    android:text="RESULTADOS" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/vol"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showMain"
    android:text="Volver" />
```

For listob.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtitem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my adpater just in case (nombres is an arraylist of Strings to fill up the ListView:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_cne);
    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaCNE);

    arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listob, R.id.txtitem,nombres);
```